# wireless networks on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless

I am unable to even view wireless networks on Ubuntu 12.10. I was using Windows 8 intitally, and have a driver Broadcom installed, yet I cannot see any networks. Do I need a different driver?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings >> software sources** and make sure that your device is enabled from the additional drivers